# UI Design for UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have experience in Android and currently started to learn iOS. I created a mechanism to Pick data in an Android App. When I click on Date button, a DatePicker pops up:

[image]

As you see It has `Cancel` and `Set` button.

My question is about my iphone App. I want to have the same mechanism. When I click on the button, Date picker pops up (that can have `Set` and `cancel` button like Android Date picker). How can I do that? I'm not sure that it is a good way in iPhone, Can you help me if we can design a better mechanism?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has a sample project that demonstrates this. You'll have to adapt it slightly: instead of showing/hiding the date picker itself, you'll want to show/hide a view containing a date picker and a dismissal button.

It's called [DateCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell).

Basically, it treats the date picker as if it were the keyboard for a cell containing the date. You'll need to manage hiding it when the user enters a text field (and thus, needs the real keyboard) and scrolling to keep the date row in view, but all the bits you need are in this project one way or the other.

Comment: I appreciate, I review the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a UX comparison between Android and iOS standard widgets, with links to the documentation on the relevant Apple / Android websites. It's a nice way to get started learning all the technical terms.

http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-6-and-android-4/

Hopefully that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be add a custom buttons to the same view containing date picker and then pop it up when the users wants. Instead of using the date picker delegate use the buttons action to get the date picker value.